React Native useCallback uses initial state values
I have the following setup when I want to track a bunch of metadata when a user listens to an audio from my app. However, for some reason, length_played always remain 0 and time_listened is inaccurate. I believe that is the case because updated values of spokenText and speakStartTime are not available when onSpeakDone callback is executed.
I am new to React Native. What can I try next?
Log
!!!
{"length": 460, "length_played": 0, "name": "San Diego", "termination_kind": "done", "time_listened": 1718124515}
!!!

Code
export default function PlaceCard({ className, isCurrent, latitude, longitude, placeName }: PlaceCardProps) {
  const { place } = usePlace(latitude, longitude, placeName)

  const { name, summary } = place

  const speaking = useAppStore(state => state.speaking)
  const setSpeaking = useAppStore(state => state.setSpeaking)
  const setCanSpeak = useAppStore(state => state.setCanSpeak)

  const [spokenText, setSpokenText] = useState('')
  const [speakStartTime, setSpeakStartTime] = useState(0)

  const unspokenText = summary.slice(spokenText.length)

  const onSpeakBoundary = useCallback(({ charIndex, charLength }: NativeBoundaryEvent) => {
    const spoken = summary.slice(0, charIndex) + summary.slice(charIndex, charIndex + charLength)
    setSpokenText(spoken)
  }, [summary])

  const onSpeakDone = useCallback((termination: string) => {
    setSpeaking(false)

    const metadata = {
      length: summary.length,
      length_played: spokenText.length,
      name,
      termination_kind: termination,
      time_listened: Math.round((Date.now() - speakStartTime) / 1000),
    }

    console.log('!!!')
    console.log(metadata)
    console.log('!!!')

    logEvent('place_summary_play', metadata)

    setSpokenText('')
    setSpeakStartTime(0)
  }, [spokenText, speakStartTime, name, summary, setSpeaking, setSpokenText, setSpeakStartTime])

  useEffect(() => {
    if (place.summaryState === 'complete')
      setCanSpeak(true)

    const options: Speech.SpeechOptions = {
      language: 'en-US',
      onBoundary: onSpeakBoundary,
      onDone: () => onSpeakDone('done'),
      onError: () => onSpeakDone('error'),
      onStart: () => setSpeakStartTime(Date.now()),
      voice: 'com.apple.ttsbundle.siri_Nicky_en-US_compact',
    }

    speaking ? Speech.speak(place.summary, options) : Speech.stop()
  }, [place.summary, place.summaryState, speaking, setCanSpeak, onSpeakDone, onSpeakBoundary])

  if (!place)
    return null

  return (
    <View>{/* rest of the irrelevant code here */}</View>
  )
}

I was expecting the updated values of spokenText and speakStartTime to be available inside onSpeakDone callback.

I suspect this is a Javascript Closure issue where even though you are correctly using the useCallback hook to create a memoized "instance" of a callback, the Speech.speak is holding on specific "instances" of the callback and the newer "instances" with the updated state closed over in scope are not used.
My suggestion here would be to cache the state/values you like to reference in the callback in a React ref that can be mutated at any time, and it's the ref "bucket" that is closed over in scope instead of the instance value at the time the callback is created.
Basic Example:
export default function PlaceCard({
  className,
  isCurrent,
  latitude,
  longitude,
  placeName
}: PlaceCardProps) {
  const { place } = usePlace(latitude, longitude, placeName);

  const { name, summary } = place;

  const speaking = useAppStore(state => state.speaking);
  const setSpeaking = useAppStore(state => state.setSpeaking);
  const setCanSpeak = useAppStore(state => state.setCanSpeak);

  const [spokenText, setSpokenText] = useState('');
  const [speakStartTime, setSpeakStartTime] = useState(0);

  const unspokenText = summary.slice(spokenText.length);

  // React refs to cache current values
  const placeRef = React.useRef(place);
  const spokenTextRef = React.useRef(spokenText);
  const speakStartTimeRef = React.useRef(speakStartTime);

  // Effect to synchronize current cached values when they update
  useEffect(() => {
    placeRef.current = place;
    speakStartTimeRef.current = speakStartTime;
    spokenTextRef.current = spokenText;
  }, [place, speakStartTime, spokenText]);

  ...

  const onSpeakDone = useCallback((termination: string) => {
    setSpeaking(false);

    // Access cached values from React refs

    const { name, summary } = placeRef.current;

    const metadata = {
      length: summary.length,
      length_played: spokenTextRef.current.length,
      name,
      termination_kind: termination,
      time_listened: Math.round((Date.now() - speakStartTimeRef.current) / 1000),
    };

    console.log(metadata);

    logEvent('place_summary_play', metadata);

    setSpokenText('');
    setSpeakStartTime(0);
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (place.summaryState === 'complete')
      setCanSpeak(true);

    const options: Speech.SpeechOptions = {
      language: 'en-US',
      onBoundary: onSpeakBoundary,
      onDone: () => onSpeakDone('done'),
      onError: () => onSpeakDone('error'),
      onStart: () => setSpeakStartTime(Date.now()),
      voice: 'com.apple.ttsbundle.siri_Nicky_en-US_compact',
    };

    speaking ? Speech.speak(place.summary, options) : Speech.stop();
  }, [
    place,
    speaking,
    setCanSpeak,
    onSpeakDone,
    onSpeakBoundary
  ]);

  ...
}


That was it. Thank you for helping out!
